# how to get output of complex number with 'i' (imaginary value ) in the output

Tags: c++, signals, fft, complex-numbers

here  is my code 4 fft calc using bluestein algorithm in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#define pi 3.14
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n, k, N;



    std::complex<double> y, z, sum = 0,  x[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1 };
    int i = sqrt(-1);
    N = 4;

    for (k = 0; k <= N - 1; k++)
    {
        y = exp(pi*k*N*k*i);

        for (n = 0; n <= N - 1; n++)
        {
            z = exp((pi*(k*k - 2 * k*n*i)) / N);
            sum += (x[n] *  z);
        }

        x[k] = (sum * y);

         cout << "The fft of x[n] is =  " << x[k] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i need out put as {6, -1-i, 0, -1+j} when v run in visual studio 2013.
if possible plz help me to declare input array generally.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your question is. What's stopping you from writing code that outputs in the format you want? And what do you mean by "declare input array"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hi david  leave abt input array.. i need to multiply complex value with integer and the output to be in complex..

Answer (score 1):

the << operator is overladed like this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt

however you can just use this to get desired output:

```
cout << "The fft of x[n] is =  " << x[k].real() << "+"<< x[k].imag()<< "i" << endl;
```

Comment: thanks nithin... but  i need to multiply complex value with integer and should get output in complex value.. my aim is to calculate BPM using fft.